The tensor package doesn't space indices well with some characters
I am using the tensor package to write tensors in my documents and I found that the indices aren't spaced well with some characters such as T or \mathcal{T}:
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage[amsthm, nc, varbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
\[ \tensor{T}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\[ \tensor{\mathrm{\mathcal{T}}}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\[ \tensor{\Lambda}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\[ \tensor{R}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\end{document}

This produces:

The indices of R and \Lambda look good, but the indices of T are slightly closer than they should be and with \mathcal{T} they're even closer. I use the newtxmath package for my math fonts (The commented line in the code). Uncommenting this line shows that this problem gets worse with those fonts:

Looking at \mathcal{T}, you almost can't tell that \nu is further than \mu. Is there a way to fix this and make sure the indices are always spaced apart correctly regardless of the character and the font used for the tensor?

The package seems to be allowing the italic correction of the base to leak out, always using a {} at the end of the base seems to fix things
newtx version:

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[amsthm, nc, varbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}
\[ \tensor{T{}}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\[ \tensor{\mathrm{\mathcal{T}}{}}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\[ \tensor{\Lambda{}}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\[ \tensor{R{}}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\end{document}

Or redefine the internal command to add the {}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[amsthm, nc, varbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tensor}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tnsr@Aux[3][]{%
  \tnsr@Erx
  \mathpalette{\tnsr@Plt{#1}{#3}}{{#2{}}}%
  \tnsr@Wrn
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\[ \tensor{T}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\[ \tensor{\mathrm{\mathcal{T}}}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\[ \tensor{\Lambda}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\[ \tensor{R}{^\mu_\nu} \]
\end{document}


This works. Thank you. As a followup question, do you know of a way to turn this into a command so I don't accidentally forget the extra braces?
I came up with \NewDocumentCommand{\Tensor}{ s o m m }{%  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%   \IfValueTF{#2}{\tensor*[#2]{#3{}}{#4}}{\tensor*{#3{}}{#4}}%  }{%   \IfValueTF{#2}{\tensor[#2]{#3{}}{#4}}{\tensor{#3{}}{#4}}%  }% }%
and while it works, it's not a very pleasant code when all I wanted was to modify the symbol argument.

If it's too much to answer in a comment, I can make a follow-up question.

@ShaiAvr I updated the answer

Nice. Thank you. I think this should be reported to the author of the tensor package. However, I can't find a git repo or something similar.

@ShaiAvr there is an email address at the top of the file
